# Java receives an error executing Ruby script; Terminal doesn't

Tags: java, ruby, terminal

This is a forked problem off of this question: [flac: "ERROR: input file has an ID3v2 tag" (it doesn't)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860835/flac-error-input-file-has-an-id3v2-tag-it-doesnt). I've solved the initial issue there but that didn't resolve one problem I was having, so I'm going to introduce it separately here.

I'm using a Ruby gem called speech2text to convert an audio file into (approximated) text. Calling it on the command line works fine (Mac Terminal). However, the following Java code:

```
String[] cmd = {"speech2text", "tmp/audio/pop-test-audio.wav"};

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = builder.start();
```

Only receives this back from the process streams:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/speech2text-0.3.4/lib/speech/audio_inspector.rb:50:in `initialize': undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/speech2text-0.3.4/lib/speech/audio_splitter.rb:77:in `new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/speech2text-0.3.4/lib/speech/audio_splitter.rb:77:in `initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/speech2text-0.3.4/lib/speech/audio_to_text.rb:15:in `new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/speech2text-0.3.4/lib/speech/audio_to_text.rb:15:in `to_text'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/speech2text-0.3.4/bin/speech2text:11
from /usr/bin/speech2text:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/speech2text:19
```

I don't know anything about Ruby, hence my lightweight use of the library through Java. I really can't tell what's going on here, but I know that it works when executed in exactly the same way from the Terminal. Has anyone got any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Hmm. The path tmp/audio... is actually within the folder of the Java Eclipse project. It worked for other programs but you might be right - it might be that Ruby isn't as welcoming. I'll check it, thanks!

Comment: Okay, full paths did not work. I tested running it on an incorrect path, and it threw a different error so we can probably rule that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also ditch the terminal and try [JRuby](http://jruby.org/). It's just as fast as the normal Ruby VM and is easier to integrate with Java.

Comment: Now there's an idea. Awesome looking library, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: This has proven difficulty in itself. speech2text is a gem (I believe) but I'm so unfamiliary with Ruby I don't know how to write the requisite Java code to execute it.

In `irb` I can run the sample Ruby code, but actually writing a Ruby script it fails to recognise the initial import, so there's further complications. Frustrating!

Comment: I've found some better resources and I have to say I think this was the way to go. While I can't solve the original problem, this answer got me to a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues trying to run jslint.js (for node.js). I actually did better running bash first, then print writing in my commands that way, but even that had problems as I recall.

Basically the problem is that executing things with Java can fail when environment settings that would otherwise be available are not loaded. This can be a tough one to solve.

Comment: Okay. I like the idea of actually running a Terminal and pumping stuff through that way! How hideous, kinda, but if it works I'll try it!

Comment: Okay, this has proved difficult - while in theory that worked, I can't work out how to get the stream of the process launched by the process (if you see what I mean) so that might not be the option.